# How to execute multiple SQL Oracle queries at once in php?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, web

I am creating a web (html css php) that takes ORDER_ID as an input. 
Then it looks into several ORACLE databases and show everything on a page.
I have optimised queries to maximum but still i am above 2 seconds per query.

The queries are not dependant on each other. 
Is there a way to simultaneously access 3 or more databases and execute queries in php ?

Or is there another way to approach this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to access the databases? I found [this old article](https://gonzalo123.com/2010/10/11/speed-up-php-scripts-with-asynchronous-database-queries), not so sure it is still any good. But the basic idea is.

Comment: Without any idea of the queries or how you are using PHP to put them together it's very difficult to be able to answer this.

Comment: Since you want your queries to run simulatneously, PDO multi query wont help. I think you should implement some sort of parallelism to achieve this, which PHP doesn't handle natively. But there are existing solutions that you'll find on Google.